# How to differentiate between click and double click in esri map (c#)?

Tags: c#, maps, arcgis, esri

I am doing a program using ArcGis API (10.2.7).
The problem is that I have an async function waiting for a click

```
   private async Task AcceptPointsAsync()
    {
        while (MapView.GetCurrentViewpoint(ViewpointType.BoundingGeometry).TargetGeometry.Extent != null)
        {
            Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.MapPoint point = await MapView.Editor.RequestPointAsync();
.
.
.
```

The problem is that before by default, it had a zoom when I did double click but know If I do it, it goes to this async method. What can I do to differenciate it?

Thanks.

Comment: if the API doesn't let you differentiate between single and double click, the only way is to wait after a click to see if it becomes a double click before acting upon it. That's pretty horrible, by the way, as you will feel a delay in the reaction of single clicks. Check if you even want to zoom on double click because that's pretty weird, or check again to see if the API has an alternative solution, or find an alternative to the API.

Comment: The problem is that this desktop app has two years development and it is done all using Commands, so I would like to remove this async method and capture an event but I don't know the property to catch it.

ie: 
    Content="{lex:Loc lbl_Imprimir}" Command="{Binding PrintCommand, ElementName=printControl}" />